# Creating a login script that stores passwords in a text file how do I create more than one password

Tags: python

I am creating a small login script and at the moment I can only store one password and username I want to store them like |username1|username2| ect. same goes for the passwords. How would I do that?

```
import sys
import time
import os

file1 = open("username.txt","r+") 

#User input for password
username = (file1.read())

username_input = input("Please type your username: ")

if username_input == username.strip(): 
    file2 = open("password.txt","r+")
    password = (file2.read())
    password_input = input("Please type your password: ")
    if password_input == password.strip():
      print("Logged In!")
    else:
      print("Sorry wrong username or password...")
else:
  print("Sorry wrong username or password!")
  exit()
```

Comment: why can you only store one username and password?

Comment: Because the function, I am striping the entire text file and not just the password or username. I don't know what I need to do to only strip the text in between the || also I need it to only need one to login.

Comment: `username_list = username.split('|')`

Comment: How would I put that in my code I keep getting an error

Comment: Use `passlib`. Much better than rolling your own. (https://passlib.readthedocs.io/en/stable/)

Answer (score 0):

You could store usernames and passwords separated by commas `,` or semicolons `;` (or any other symbol) and use the `.split(sep=',')` method of strings to separate the file's contents.

```
names = username.split(',')
```

`.split()` will return a list of strings which you could then search for the user input with:

```
idx = names.index(username_input)
```

which returns the index of the input, if found. Finally, compare the split passwords array at position `idx` to the password the user typed in:

```
if password[idx] == password_input:
   # login successful
```

For this to work, usernames and passwords would need to be stored in the same order though.

Full code:

```
import sys
import time
import os

# read usernames file
file1 = open("username.txt","r+") 
usernames = (file1.read())
names = usernames.split(','). 
# assumes, that usernames are stored like <name1>, <name2>, <name3>

# find index of username in the list of username
idx = names.index(username_input)

#User input for password
username_input = input("Please type your username: ")

if username_input == names[idx]: 
    # read passwords file
    file2 = open("password.txt","r+")
    passwords = (file2.read())
    words = passwords.split(',')
    # again, assumes, that passwords are stored like <pass1>, <pass2>, <pass3>

    password_input = input("Please type your password: ")

    if words[idx] == password_input:
        print("Logged In!")
    else:
        print("Sorry wrong username or password...")
else:
    print("Sorry wrong username or password!")
    exit()
```

If you want to go even further, you could try storing them in a csv-file instead of plain text (which is basically also just strings separated by commas and line breaks). I would also suggest encrypting/hashing the passwords if you want to use this for actual authentication.

Comment: Still can you put it in my code I dont understand how to put this into my code, sorry kind of new.

Answer (score 0):

The common way (eg the standard Unix password file) is to have one line per user with a known structure (delimited is generally enough).

For example, assuming you forbid colons (`:`) in both usernames and passwords

It could give :

```
...
file = open("username.txt","r") 

username_input = input("Please type your username: ")
password_input = input("Please type your password: ")

# find username in file :
for line in file:
    username, password = line.split(':')[:2]  # allow additional fields after the password
    if username_input == username.strip():
        # found; let's look at the password
        if password_input == password.strip():
          print("Logged In!")
        else:
          print("Sorry wrong username or password...")
        break      # do not search the file any further
else:
  # username not found in file
  print("Sorry wrong username or password!")
```

But (common security warning), except for learning, **never** store a password in plain text but only a hash of it